# Batch - Is it possible to create a batch file thats check if a website / url redirect to another site

Tags: url, redirect, batch-file

Is it possible to create a batch file thats check if a website / url redirect to another site?

for example check if http://www.google.com/ redirect to http://www.google.com/randomsite.php/ and i would be great if it could do a status like:

```
www.google.dk/ Redirects to www.google.dk/randomsite.php/
```

for example with echo and some varible like:

```
echo %Google1% Redirects to %Google2%
```

And that would look like this

```
www.google.dk/ Redirects to www.google.dk/randomsite.php/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no built-in tools in Windows, but if you download a [Windows compatible version of curl](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html), you can use that to print the headers. This [blog articl](http://beerpla.net/2010/06/10/how-to-display-just-the-http-response-code-in-cli-curl/)e seems a good place to start.

For example:

```
curl -sL http://www.stackoverflow.com --head | find "301" OR
curl -sL http://www.stackoverflow.com --head | find "302"
```

If found, the %ERRORLEVEL% variable will be greater than 0, so you can check that.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, `curl -I http://yoururl.com`. You just need the first line, so start maybe with `curl -I http://yoururl.com | head -n 1`